# Webview Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant

Tags: android, webview, sslv3

I am unable to logged into a website(https://healthmanager.webmd.com/manager/) in my application using webView.Error is below

```
external/chromium/net/http/http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc:865: [0805/114317:WARNING:http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc(865)] Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant:
```

My websetting is below

```
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    MyPortalsWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        MyPortalsWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
```

Is there any setting is missing or something else needs to be done?

Comment: is this issue resolved

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to just remove the ssl error message, set web view client and override onReceivedSslError() method.

```
    MyPortalsWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
                handler.proceed();
            }
    });
```

Comment: I am using samsung note 3 with Android 4.3 and its working fine on mobile  browser but not in my application.

Comment: This is extremely insecure and will not pass Google Play deployment process.